# Using Pandas to fill NaN entries based on values in a different column, using a dictionary as a guide

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a large dataframe where I'm trying to populate the NaN entries of column B based on the values in column A, using a dictionary as a guide. For example:

```
df = 
   A    B 
0  Red  628  
1  Red  149  
2  Red  NaN  
3  Green  575  
4  Green  687
5  Green  NaN
6  Blue  159
7  Blue  NaN
```

and the dictionary is (for example)

```
dict = {"Red": 123, "Green": 456, "Blue": 789}
```

I am curious as to the best way to replace each NaN with the corresponding number from the dictionary using Pandas. I'm not sure how to use the .fillna() or .isnull() methods in this situation.  I'm new to Pandas so any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: This is what value attribute is for. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html. It can take dict and be applied for index or columns.

Comment: Is your index really consecutive `4`'s? is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the relevant `rows` using `boolean indexing` [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), and `map` your `dictionary` to translate `A` to `B` values where necessary:

```
na_map = {"Red": 123, "Green": 456, "Blue": 789}
mask = df.B.isnull()
```

`mask` looks as follows:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7     True
```

Finally:

```
df.loc[mask, 'B'] = df.loc[mask, 'A'].map(na_map)

       A    B
0    Red  628
1    Red  149
2    Red  123
3  Green  575
4  Green  687
5  Green  456
6   Blue  159
7   Blue  789
```

Comment: I'm only trying to replace the NaN values, so Red would read 628, 149, 123 - not 123,123,123 - if that makes sense?  I tried df.B.isnull() = df.A.map(map) and got SyntaxError: can't assign to function call.

Comment: Sorry, misread. See updated answer. Just apply `.map()` to relevant `rows` with missing values.

Comment: two thing s about this soln. 1) `map` is a builitin name and you should avoid using that and 2) you are calling `df.B.isnull()` twice which is a bad practice. its not the most pythonic soln tho'. see @EdChum 's soln.

Comment: How is setting and resetting the `index` more pythonic than using `boolean indexing`?

Comment: I don't have a very strong opinion on whether `masking` & `mapping` or `fillna` is more pythonic. Out of interest, I checked performance: 1.24ms for  `Masking` & `mapping` vs 8.76ms for `fillna` on a `DataFrame` with 80k rows, ie, 10k times the sample above. Not too big a deal, I'd say both approaches appear quite reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.  Both approaches do what I need on my dataset.  Thanks Stefan for also checking the computation times between the two functions, its good to see how they compare.

Answer (score 2):

I think your index looks iffy, the following does what you want:

```
In [19]:
df['B'] = df.set_index('A')['B'].fillna(d).reset_index()['B']

df
Out[19]:
       A    B
0    Red  628
1    Red  149
2    Red  123
3  Green  575
4  Green  687
5  Green  456
6   Blue  159
7   Blue  789
```

Here we set the index to column 'A' and then call `fillna` passing your dict, this performs the lookup using the index ('A') to return the associated dict value, we then reset the index and overwrite column 'B'

Comment: this is the correct answer. btw since you are already setting index without `inplace=True` you might as well do `df =df.set_index('A')['B'].fillna(d).reset_index()`. No need for extra column getattr

Comment: @goofd true but usually these questions are more specific and this overwrites a specific column rather than taking the entire df if it had more columns but you're correct in this case

Comment: btw the way set_index is implemented the following command `df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x: fill_kwds[x['A']] if pd.isnull(x['B']) else x['B'], axis=1)` is way faster (takes 469$\mu$s compared to 1.02 ms using set_index)

Comment: That is true on this toy dataset but `apply` does not scale well as it's just a `for` loop

Comment: well depends. on the newer pandas they do appear to be a bit more than that. see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#pure-python. But i agree this is the what I would do, more cleaner. thats why the upvote from me :D

Comment: it isn't vectorised and `apply` should be avoided where possible