# Replace NaNs in pandas DataFrame based on row entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in which each row represents a single doctor's visit, and each column contains data from a single diagnostic test. The data is incomplete, with missing values filled with NaN.

Here is a simplified example:

```
       AGE Height     SEX Weight
0   79     40    Male     90
1   79     21    Male     20
2   79    NaN    Male     50
3   79     89    Male    NaN
4   79     90    Male     57
5   81     87  Female    NaN
6   81    NaN  Female     89
7   81     54  Female     79
8   81     21  Female    NaN
9   81     23  Female     23
```

I want to replace each NaN with a population mean for patients of the same sex and age. I've been able to create a DataFrame that contains the means for every AGE and SEX combination with the following:

```
age_sex_means = df.groupby(['SEX', 'AGE'])['Height','Weight'].mean()
```

Which yields the following DataFrame:

```
                Height  Weight
SEX    AGE                
Female 81     37.0    38.2
Male   79     48.0    43.4
```

But I cannot find a method to replace the NaNs in the first DataFrame with the means contained in the second. Both [Using Pandas to fill NaN entries based on values in a different column, using a dictionary as a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600056/using-pandas-to-fill-nan-entries-based-on-values-in-a-different-column-using-a) seems to address a similar situation to mine, but with only one index which obviously won't work in my exact case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
You can use `apply` coupled with `fillna`

```
df.groupby(['AGE', 'SEX'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

   AGE  Height     SEX     Weight
0   79   40.00    Male  90.000000
1   79   21.00    Male  20.000000
2   79   60.00    Male  50.000000
3   79   89.00    Male  54.250000
4   79   90.00    Male  57.000000
5   81   87.00  Female  63.666667
6   81   46.25  Female  89.000000
7   81   54.00  Female  79.000000
8   81   21.00  Female  63.666667
9   81   23.00  Female  23.000000
```

---

**Option 2**
Use `transform` and `combine_first` to produce a copy

```
df.combine_first(df.groupby(['SEX', 'AGE']).transform('mean'))

   AGE  Height     SEX     Weight
0   79   40.00    Male  90.000000
1   79   21.00    Male  20.000000
2   79   60.00    Male  50.000000
3   79   89.00    Male  54.250000
4   79   90.00    Male  57.000000
5   81   87.00  Female  63.666667
6   81   46.25  Female  89.000000
7   81   54.00  Female  79.000000
8   81   21.00  Female  63.666667
9   81   23.00  Female  23.000000
```

---

**Option 3**
Same thing with `fillna`

```
df.fillna(df.groupby(['SEX', 'AGE']).transform('mean'))

   AGE  Height     SEX     Weight
0   79   40.00    Male  90.000000
1   79   21.00    Male  20.000000
2   79   60.00    Male  50.000000
3   79   89.00    Male  54.250000
4   79   90.00    Male  57.000000
5   81   87.00  Female  63.666667
6   81   46.25  Female  89.000000
7   81   54.00  Female  79.000000
8   81   21.00  Female  63.666667
9   81   23.00  Female  23.000000
```

---

**Option 4**
Or edit in place with `update`

```
df.update(df.groupby(['SEX', 'AGE']).transform('mean'))
df

   AGE  Height     SEX     Weight
0   79   40.00    Male  90.000000
1   79   21.00    Male  20.000000
2   79   60.00    Male  50.000000
3   79   89.00    Male  54.250000
4   79   90.00    Male  57.000000
5   81   87.00  Female  63.666667
6   81   46.25  Female  89.000000
7   81   54.00  Female  79.000000
8   81   21.00  Female  63.666667
9   81   23.00  Female  23.000000
```